# magento cli not working for any command and gives a long error

Tags: magento2, module, error, cache, cli

i have magento 2.2.3 . for deleting cache or enabling modules or any other usage of magento cli i take one error . it begins with this phrase

> Unknown package has no name defined

and it is continuing with this long  json terms error
[image]

and at the end it finished with this

[image]

i get these long senetces error for any cli magento command . one told me to install baintree but i check this module .it was installed before.
the instersting part is my project works in windows and it doesnt show me error on cli in windows os. but my server is linux and in docker container i run my same magento project and get error on CLI commands. how should i resolve that? my php version in both is same(linux and windows)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you got the same PHP version and everything, i guess that you are just missing dependent vendor packages inside the linux docker container? Try `composer install` command in project root to fix it. Afterwards run the cli command again and it should work.
Good luck

Comment: yes, u are right. cli works until I add a new package by composer require (package_name) --ignore-platform-reqs.. after that it gives me this error. how should I add a new module to Magento by the composer  ?

Comment: Why do you use the flag `--ignore-plattform-reqs` while adding new composer packages? You should probably try to run it without the flag and everything should be fine regarding the cli. Alternatively you could also check the composer docs for further reference: https://getcomposer.org/doc/01-basic-usage.md. As is read out from there you first require a package afterwards you need to run `composer update`, so that you have the requirement inside the composer.lock file. Afterwards you run the `composer install` command that I mentioned above already.

Comment: thanks for helping. finally, I change my composer version to install dependencies. your speech guides me to think about my vendor packages.